# Orientation restarts my app

Tags: android, android-fragments, orientation, screen-rotation, savestate

Im new to programing, I have a naviagation drawer with fragments. When i rotate my device it "restarts the app" or calls the Home fragment. Im not sure how to fix this im gessing it is related to the super.onCreate (savedInstance) but havent found how to implement it. I also tryed with the onConfigurationChanged method on my manifest with no luck. I ve been copying code from different tutorials to make my app work so im not sure if the code im posting should be the one I should post.  Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ImageView home;
    Fragment fragment = null;
    TextView appname;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    List<String> listDataHeader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String fontPath = "neue.ttf";
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        home = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.home);
        home.setOnClickListener(homeOnclickListener);
        appname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.appname);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), fontPath);
        appname.setTypeface(tf);

        setUpDrawer();
    }

    private void setUpDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerListener);
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
        prepareListData();
        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        fragment = new Home();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(expListView);

        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                                    switch (groupPosition) {
                                        case 0:
                                            switch (childPosition) {
                                                case 0:
                                                    fragment = new 1();
                                                    break;
                                                case 1:
                                                    fragment = new 2();
                                                    break;
                                                case 2:
                                                    fragment = new 3();
                                                    break;
                            ...
                        }
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        switch (childPosition) {
                            case 0:
                                fragment = new 4();
                                break;
                           ...
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        break;

                    ...
                }
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(expListView);
                return false;
            }
        });

    }...
```

Comment: In your manifest file add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your Activity tag. This prevents the Activity from destroying and creating again on orientation change. Also, have your Activity extend AppCompatActivity from the support library; this is a better approach for backwards compatibility and will ensure that the configeChanges tag will work.

Comment: Thanks i try it but it didnt work

Comment: As Shadab Ansari pesponded that answer help me alot but i had to go over other problems, at last i found a solution to the rotation problem in an other way that did not crashed my app, if you want to see it is here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36900671/app-crashing-after-i-rotate-device-and-click-the-menu/36901929#36901929

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On device rotation, activity is restarted - this is the apparent behavior. If you don't want your activity to get recreated, you should add `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your `Manifest` file for that activity.

Otherwise you can prevent calling  `setUpDrawer()` when your activity gets restarted by checking `savedInstanceState` like this -

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String fontPath = "neue.ttf";
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        home = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.home);
        home.setOnClickListener(homeOnclickListener);
        appname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.appname);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), fontPath);
        appname.setTypeface(tf);

       if(savedInstanceState == null){
           setUpDrawer();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! the android:configChanges="orientation" didnt work, but the if(savedInstanceState == null){
           setUpDrawer();
      } did it

Comment: Now the app is crashing after I rotated and i try to open the menu. 
error .MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:140)
View.OnClickListener homeOnclickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(expListView)){
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(expListView);
                }else{
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(expListView);
                }
            }
        };

Comment: You should initialize all your views  outside if block  including those views which are  in   `setUpDrawer()`. Remove views initialization from `setUpDrawer()`.

Comment: Thanks i doulbe checked and views are outside. still crashing.

Comment: Ok sure but question about that, should I edit my question, or hit the answer button and post the code there?

Comment: I roled back the edit and added a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36900671/app-crashing-after-i-rotate-device-and-click-the-menu